# Removing leading 0s in a numeric string

Tags: c#, string

For instance, if there is a string "000001234090883450". How do I remove the first "0" Normally I would have used substring and then removed the first five "0" using string.Remove. But it will cut all the "0" in the string. Is it somehow possible to remove ONLY the first five "0", leaving rest of the string intact?

EDIT: I apologize if I was not specific enough. What I wanted to say is that the number of "0" in that string isn't constant. The "0" are user inputs so next time it could be: "000123325435043540035"

Comment: [`str = Regex.Replace(str, @"^0+", "");`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7f5w83z.aspx)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have many options - If you want to trim off all leading zero characters, a simple option would be:

```
var result = "000001234090883450".TrimStart('0');
```

---

> Normally I would have used substring and then removed the first five

As you mentioned `Substring`, you can also use `Substring` to remove the first 5 characters (if you want to just always remove 5 characters).  There is no reason to use `Remove` if you're already using `Substring`:

```
var result = "000001234090883450".Substring(5);
```

Comment: Yes but the first "0" can be changed at any time...That's the problem

Comment: @Ajay_C What do you mean "can be changed at any time"?

Comment: @Ajay_C `TrimStart` will trim off ALL of the `'0'` characters from the start - there could be any number (including zero of them) at the start, and it trims them all.

Comment: Oh okay...I just used it but first I need to ask if it contains any "0" at the beginning is this the correct way?

if(string.Substring(0,1)=="0")
 then string.Trimstart('0')

Comment: @Ajay_C Just do `theString = theString.TrimStart('0');` - There's no need to check.  If the string doesn't start with a 0, the result will be the same.

Comment: Well first of all thanks because my program is working perfectly now.
I apologize, I didn't mention that this is a part of a bigger programm because it would have just been more confusing. I needed the if statement, because I needed to add a "1" in front of the number IF there wasn't any "0" at the beginning of the string.

I know I may sound really dumb now but I'm an inexperienced student with moderate knowledge about C#.

Answer (score 1):

Another interpretation: You want to remove the leading `"00000"` from every occurrence of the string `"000001234090883450"`. This can be done using regex lookahead:

```
string s = Regex.Replace("...000001234090883450...", "00000(?=1234090883450)", "");
// Result: "...1234090883450..."
```

Answer (score 1):

If the format of the string is predictable you can use conversion:

```
var s = "000001234090883450";
s = long.Parse(s).ToString(); // convert string to long and then back to string
```

Answer (score 1):

@Ajay_C: If your problem actually is as you stated in a comment:

> I needed the if statement, because I needed to add a "1" in front of the number
>   IF there wasn't any "0" at the beginning of the string.

Then you want something like this:

```
class Program
{
  static string TransformUserInput( string s )
  {
    if ( s == null ) throw new ArgumentNullException("s") ;
    string transformed = "" ;
    if ( s.Length > 0 )
    {
      transformed = rxLeadingZeros.Replace(s, m => m.Length == 0 ? "1" : m.Length == s.Length ? "0" : "" ) ;
    }
    return transformed ;
  }
  private static readonly Regex rxLeadingZeros = new Regex( @"^0*");

  static void Main( string[] args )
  {
    string [] values = { "" , "0" , "000" , "000000987654321000" , "54321000" , "0000000000000000000000000000000" , "000000000000000000009876543210" , } ;
    foreach ( string raw in values )
    {
      string cooked = TransformUserInput(raw) ;
      Console.WriteLine( "raw    : {0}",raw) ;
      Console.WriteLine( "cooked : {0}",cooked);
      Console.WriteLine() ;
    }
    return;
  }
}
```

which does the following:

- matches all the leading zero `0` characters (which might be none)
- if the string is empty, returns the empty string.
- otherwise, returns the string created by transforming it:

  - If the match length is zero (meaning no leading zeroes), a `1` is prepended to the string,
  - Otherwise, if the match length is the length of the entire source string (meaning the source string is *all* zeroes, a single `0` is returned
  - Otherwise (we matched 1 or more leading zeroes but not the entire source string), we replace the leading zeroes with the empty (nil) string `String.Empty`.

Here's the output:

```
raw    :
cooked :

raw    : 0
cooked : 0

raw    : 000
cooked : 0

raw    : 000000987654321000
cooked : 987654321000

raw    : 54321000
cooked : 154321000

raw    : 0000000000000000000000000000000
cooked : 0

raw    : 000000000000000000009876543210
cooked : 9876543210
```